# IntelliJ list of warnings

Tags: intellij-idea, warnings

When I do a version control commit in IntelliJ, it generates a convenient list of code warnings in the Messages tab. How do I regenerate this list without doing a commit? I'm not interested in all inspection messages, I'm only interested in those warning messages which would be displayed during the commit.

Answer (score 29):

Can't you just make a custom inspection profile with the stuff you want (I have 5 different profiles that I choose between depending on what I want to check)?

> Analyze -> Inspect Code -> Inspection profile -> ...

or

> File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections